# calculus book recommendations

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

i want to learn single variable calculus i completed schooling and i love calculus for now i am focusing on single variable calculus i tried many books like Calculus - "A Complete Course 7th ed - R. Adams, C. Essex (Pearson Canada, 2010) BBS" and Dawkins part one and two but they feel like pretty basic to me then i got to know about spivak that book is really tough i cant solve most of it and no solutions are available i learned all of calculus on my own we dont have good teachers here and i cant buy books because they are not available here i just download them from torrent if its available so i have a real problem here so what i want is a book that covers all of single variable calculus differential equation is not necessary i am thinking of learning it separately so what i want is a book that would contain fairly tough question and their solutions too if you could provide link to free digital copy it would be great.

so i am more interested in proofs and theorems but i must be able to do problems based on them to not the ones with direct application but little hard and not as hard as spivak's

Comment: There is a [solution manual](http://www.amazon.com/Combined-Answer-Calculus-Fourth-Editions/dp/0914098926/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1459781678&sr=1-2&keywords=spivak+calculus) available for Spivak's book.

Comment: I am closing this question, as there are very many calculus book recommendation questions on this site already, and there has been no substantial change meriting a new such question.

Comment: I have chosen merely one of the many calculus questions to choose as a duplicate for this question.

Comment: thanks i am new here and as of the solution to spivak thanks but amazon does not deliver here